# Trying to do slider on react

Tags: reactjs

Ok, I want this behavior: when I click on my 'row__button', div 'row__posters' (on pic) should scroll right or left, no idea how to do this in react.

```
<button onClick={handleSlider} className='row__button'>
  <ArrowBackIosIcon className='row__ArrowBackIosIcon' />
</button>

<div className='row__posters'>..........</div>

const handleSlider = () => {
  {/*('.row__posters').scroll(100, 0)*/} //something like that lol
}
```

[image: pic with slider]

Comment: you can use owlCarousel instead of it this is working fine with reactJs...

Comment: Ok nice, but actualy I already solved my problem with useRef and scrollBy